# How to make this code more reusable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the best way of making this code reusable.

I need, instead of "Aa0" in function and variables names, to also be able to have Aa1, Aa2, Ab0... (40 times)

I know I could just copy-paste and change those letters (and repeat the process 40 times), but this is definitely not the cleaner approach.

Is there a way to make every instance of "Aa0" some kind of variable that can hold multiple values?

```
function mov_Aa0() {
    var div_bor_Aa0 = document.getElementsByClassName("bor_Aa0");

    for (var div_bor_Aa0_i = 0; div_bor_Aa0_i < div_bor_Aa0.length; div_bor_Aa0_i++) {
        div_bor_Aa0[div_bor_Aa0_i].style.borderColor = "#FFF";
    }

    var div_txt_box_Aa0 = document.getElementById("txt_box_Aa0");
    var par_txt_Aa0 = '<p class="txt">main title</p><br /><p class="txt">sub title</p>';
    div_txt_box_Aa0.innerHTML = par_txt_Aa0;
    var par_key_Aa0 = '<p class="txt g">some text</p><br /><p class="txt o">not</p><p class="txt g">important</p>';
    div_key_box_Dd1.innerHTML = par_key_Aa0;
    div_map_box_Dd2.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/Dd2/map/map_Aa0.png)";
}

var div_con_box_Aa0 = document.getElementById("con_box_Aa0");

div_con_box_Aa0.onmouseover = mov_Aa0;
```

I hope the explanation is clear enough.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is `div_key_box_Dd1` and `div_map_box_Dd2` those will be overridden based on your specs for Aa1,Aa2 and so fort?

Comment: "Some kind of variable that can hold multiple values" is called an array or a collection.

Comment: Don't duplicate the function, instead make it take a parameter `function mov_something(which_thing) { ...` and call `mov_something("Aa0")` using the "which_thing" like `getElementsByClassName("bor" + which_thing)`

Comment: div_key_box_Dd1 and div_map_box_Dd2 are global variables. Each one of those 40 functions will use them so they should not be changed.

Comment: "Not be changed" and yet they are being assigned by one of your Asomething

Comment: So figure out some better way to store the data! In an array, or an object, or as data attached to the elements, for instance.

Comment: @Dalorzo, I wanted to say those two should stay Dd1 and Dd2 respectively.

Comment: Dd2 background `map_Aa0.png` will be overridden on your second Aa2 call and so fort, it does not make sense.

Comment: div_map_box_Dd2 is small div that will change background depending on the div the mouse is hovering on. If it hovers above div_con_box_Aa0, the background will be map_Aa0.png, if it howers above Ab1 background will be map_Ab1.png and so on. Sorry, my english is not very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a function which takes and argument which keeps changing for each element and assign the hover function to each element with different arguments.

```
function mov(x){
    var div_bor = document.getElementsByClassName("bor_"+x);
    for (var div_bor_i = 0; div_bor_i < div_bor.length; div_bor_i ++){
        div_bor[div_bor_i].style.borderColor = "#FFF";
    };
    var div_txt_box = document.getElementById("txt_box_"+x);
    var par_txt = '<p class="txt">main title</p><br /><p class="txt">sub title</p>';
    div_txt_box.innerHTML = par_txt;
    var par_key = '<p class="txt g">some text</p><br /><p class="txt o">not</p><p class="txt g">important</p>';
    div_key_box_Dd1.innerHTML = par_key;
    div_map_box_Dd2.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/Dd2/map/map_"+x+".png)";
}

var div_con_box_Aa0 = document.getElementById("con_box_Aa0");
div_con_box_Aa0.onmouseover = function(){ 
    mov('Aa0');
}
```

I suggest u can add and attribute to the element which keeps changing and access that attribute dynamically in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a 2D array to store these values?  Specifically, you could use array[n] for storing all the elements with suffix n.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few recommendations on my part:

```
div_bor[div_bor_i].style.borderColor = "#FFF";
```

Looks like it could be transformed to css **hover**, since the event as your described it is mouse event:

```
.AaSomething:hover {
      border-color:#ffffff;
 }
```

This same principle applies for `div_map_box_Dd2.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/Dd2/map/map_Aa0.png)";` which could also use the `hover` css instead of writing code for it.

These sections in your code seems to be constants, for example: `div_key_box_Dd1` is being assigned a value that never changes:

```
 var par_txt_Aa = '<p class="txt">main title</p><br /><p class="txt">sub title</p>';
 var par_key_Aa = '<p class="txt g">some text</p><br /><p class="txt o">not</p><p class="txt g">important</p>';
 div_key_box_Dd1.innerHTML = par_key_Aa;
```

And if you do all that I think there is not need for this function to exists.